# Payment Module Error

Tags: magento-1.9, payment

I am seeing an error/notice in my Magento install when I have errors enabled, it is displayed after the response from the payment gateway.

I believe this error is being caused when magento is saving the order and updating the payment status.

```
$order->addStatusToHistory(
   $model->getConfigData('order_successful_status'),
   Mage::helper('CUSTOM')->__($orderInfo),
   $order->getPayment()->setAdditionalInformation('Information',$orderInfo)
);          

$order->save();
$order->sendNewOrderEmail();
```

This is the error that I am getting:

```
Notice: Object of class Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment could not be converted to int  in ...\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php on line 2935
```

Under this I then see:

```
#0 ...\magento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(2935): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Object of class...', 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs...', 2935, Array)
#1 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Abstract.php(221): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->prepareColumnValue(Array, Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Payment))
#2 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(586): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Abstract->_prepareDataForTable(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History), 'sales_flat_orde...')
#3 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Resource\Abstract.php(50): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_prepareDataForSave(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History))
#4 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Abstract.php(449): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Abstract->_prepareDataForSave(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History))
#5 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Resource\Order\Abstract.php(425): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History))
#6 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(318): Mage_Sales_Model_Resource_Order_Abstract->save(Object(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History))
#7 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\Abstract.php(652): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#8 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order.php(2219): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->save()
#9 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(319): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->_afterSave()
#10 ...\magento\app\code\community\CUSTOM_MODULE\controllers\PaymentController.php(105): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#11 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Action.php(418): CUSTOM_PaymentController->returnAction()
#12 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Router\Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('return')
#13 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien\Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->\match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 ...\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 ...\magento\app\Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 ...\magento\index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
```

Any clues to what could be causing this would really help.

Thanks

Comment: Can i get this revised now i have made some changes?